# Need solution to rand_range providing only floats and not integers - GDScript

Tags: random, integer, gdscript

For a project, I need to make use of a random number generator to provide random numbers as part of a Fisher-Yates Shuffle. I am using both `randomize()` and `randi()%1+50` methods to get my random numbers.

However doing it this way does not let my Fisher-Yates shuffler count down to `n=0`, because if it does, it kicks out an error:

> Division By Zero in operator %

Pointing right at my generator range where the % resides. I can work around this by using `rand_range()`, however, because `rand_range()` returns a float and not an integer, I am forced to round the result, which sometimes results in duplicate numbers, which I cannot have.

`ceil()` and `floor()` are also out of the question for the same reason. This, of course, could all be solved if `GDScript` included something like `randi_range()` but I have seen on other forums that this has been a problem since 2014, and to which there still is no solution.

**Q:** Given that this is not an option, does anyone know a way to return a random number, within a range, that does not include 0 and is a positive integer that doesn't require the % operator to dictate the range?

Don't get me wrong, I love the Godot engine, and appreciate it for what it is, but sometimes the code requires a tad too much "wrestling" for my mental sanity to handle.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Godot has a class [RandomNumberGenerator](http://docs.godotengine.org/fr/latest/classes/class_randomnumbergenerator.html#class-randomnumbergenerator-method-randi-range) that does implement randi_range().

Here's a FisherYates Shuffle to prove to myself that it should work:

```
extends Node2D
var deck = []

func init_deck():
    var arr = []
    for i in range(1,52):
        arr.append(i)
    return arr

# Called when the node enters the scene tree for the first time.
func _ready():
    deck = init_deck()
    var n = len(deck) 
    print(fy_shuffle(deck, n))
    pass # Replace with function body.

#Fisher Yates Shuffle
func fy_shuffle (arr, n): 
    # Start from the last element and swap one by one. 
    var rng = RandomNumberGenerator.new()

    for i in range(n-1,0,-1): 
    # Pick a random index from 0 to i 
        var j = rng.randi_range(0,i+1) 
        # Swap arr[i] with the element at random index
        var t1 = arr[i]
        var t2 = arr[j] 
        arr[i] = t2
        arr[j] = t1

    return arr
```

Comment: Well, i'll be damned. Exactly what I was needing. Just out of curiosity, do you have any idea when this was added to Godot?

Comment: Looks like [about 5 months ago](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/commit/d376be2bf4c8c8b5bfcb650647ebb73605f8fc81)

Comment: Ahh. So it was there the whole time... Thanks for pointing it out though, it's hard enough finding answers to Godot questions, especially regarding 3.1. One of the downsides of not yet being a "big player", like unity or unreal I suppose.

Comment: You're an early adopter from the look of it.  I was looking at their core tutorials and there was UI bugs that were recently fixed apparently but the version of Godot I had was 2 months old.  I spent a good long time trying to figure out wtf I was doing wrong.  I get the sense that it's gaining momentum though even if it's still a small fraction of the commercial alternatives.

Comment: It has the potential... if people only knew. I guess most folks think "small dice" when they see the words "free" and "open source" even though there are plenty examples to the contrary. I must admit, though, even I was taken aback at first by the 50mb download size. Oh well, due to the recent, rather large displays of incompetency by several AAA game publishers, i'm sure there will be a growing space for independent developers to thrive, and for that, they'll need a good, straightforward engine. Hopefully then it will receive the large community support it rightfully deserves.

Answer (score 0):

```
const START = 10
const STOP = 20

var random = RandomNumberGenerator.new()
random.randomize()

var n = random.randi_range(START, STOP)
```